# How do I read a custom header in a GRPC server side service in Quarkus?

Tags: java, header, grpc, interceptor, quarkus

I have seen some java examples of how to write a ServerInterceptor to read a custom header from the metadata, but can't find anything on how to attach the interceptor to the service in Quarkus e.g. for this: https://quarkus.io/guides/grpc-service-implementation
Or is there another, easier way of reading a custom header in Quarkus, e.g. to get a token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this useful example in the Quarkus Zulip chat from a friendly user:

https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/integration-tests/grpc-interceptors/src/main/java/io/quarkus/grpc/examples/interceptors/HeaderServerInterceptor.java

No need to attach or register the interceptor anywhere.